# Can I create a website on wordpress anonymously?

Tags: vpn, wordpress, websites

If I use a VPN that doesn't keep logs and create an email account, then use that email account to create a wordpress website (still using the VPN) and give no personal information (address, name, etc.) then how anonymous would I be from this website? Additionally, there would be no ad revenues or no credit cards linked to the account for anything. How easy or how else could my identity be compromised?

Comment: Have you considered using Tor instead of a VPN?

Comment: hmm, that's a good idea. maybe both tor and a vpn. can i access emails and wordpress accounts through tor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel if you want to remain completely anonymous, then creating a new email address with no other association to your self then that alone should be able to manage that. 
Again with the use of a VPN you should again be ok, depending on the service your using. As there could be some DNS leak and as a result you could potentially have information leaked.

For this I would recommend [Disable WebRTC](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/happy-bonobo-disable-webrtc/), as for how easily your ID could be compromised would depend on how similar your user name etc is to your own personal ones. But as long as you creat all new accounts and use [Random Name Generator](http://www.fakenamegenerator.com) you should be ok!